# Problems with gulp and gulp-diff

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'm wanting my gulpfile.js to compare what is in my angular concatenated file before it has ng-annotate run and after so I can see what injections it made.  I can't quite get the syntax.  I keep getting different versions of the error which says gulp can not stat my file.

The code that I'm stuck on is below.  I'd be happy to do it in one pass but had no success with that either.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {

    gulp.src(['public/app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('main-noanotate.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.noannotate.js'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'));


    return gulp.src(['public/app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(diff('main.noannotate.js'))
        .pipe(diff.reporter({ fail: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'))
});
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this.  I got it sort of working (posted a blog post) but it still is not right.  I can't run my scripts task inside a normal full gulp default processing.  http://peterkellner.net/2014/11/14/angular-ngannotate-better-way/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gulp-diff` is trying to diff against the original source file, but there is no original source file on disk as you're working with the result of a concatenation of multiple files. I recommend splitting out your gulp tasks and writing to a temporary `.build` directory.

Here is an example of clearing a build workspace.

To set things up, create a new directory and run:

```
npm install del gulp gulp-concat gulp-diff gulp-header; mkdir -p src; echo "foo" > src/foo.txt; echo "bar" > src/bar.txt
```

Then create this gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var diff = require('gulp-diff');
var header = require('gulp-header');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('default', ['clean']);

gulp.task('clean', ['build'], function(cb) {
  del(['.build'], cb);
});

gulp.task('build', ['concat'], function() {
  return gulp.src('.build/all.txt')
    .pipe(header('//stream test\n'))
    .pipe(diff())
    .pipe(diff.reporter())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('concat', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.txt')
    .pipe(concat('all.txt'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.build'));
});
```

Then try running `gulp`. It should concat the file and put the output into the temporary `.build` directory. That file is then used to diff against. In the above example `header` is doing the job of amending the file (this might be where you apply `ngAnnotate` instead).

Comment: Perfect! just tested and it works every time. I owe you Mr. Sky!